# Contradiction in the application of the Sylow Theorem on the alternating group $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

Somehow I get a contradiction in the following application of the Sylow Theorem.

If $G$ is a group with cardinality $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ there are exactly $4$ or $24$ elements of order $5$. I have already shown that.

The question is which of these cases hold for the alternating group $A_5$. My approach was as following:

Cardinality of $A_5$ is indeed $60$, so that is okay. Now, I note that:

$A_5 = \{\sigma \in S_5|sgn(\sigma) = 1\}$

This means that if $\sigma \in A_5$ I can write $\sigma$ as the product of even transpositions since $sgn(\sigma) = 1$. So:

$\sigma = \tau_1 \dots \tau_{2n}$. Now, to compute the order of $\sigma$ I can use that:

$ord(\sigma) = lcm(l(\tau_1), \dots,l(\tau_{2_n}))$ where $lcm$ stands for the least common multiple and $l$ for the length of a cycle (in this case the transposition). But since $\tau_i$'s are transpositions their length is $2$. And the least common multiple of all the lengths is therefore $2$ as well. So the order of the arbitrary element from $A_5$ is $2$. But this contradicts to the fact that there must exists a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $A_5$ and that it either has $4$ or $24$ elements with order $5$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: That formula for the order only works if the cycles are disjoint ie act on different elements eg $ord((12)(23)) = 3$

Comment: @user24142 How is $(12)(23)$ defined? Is $(12)$ not the cycle that sends $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$? Therefore I do not understand how $2$ can be send to $3$ as well?

Comment: $(12)(23)$ is a composition of functions. Normally the rightmost function is applied first (but some authors do it the other way, so do check your book). So the element $2$ is first sent to $3$ by $(23)$. The permutation $(12)$ doesn't do anything to $3$, and therefore the composition maps $2\mapsto 3$. Similarly, $(23)$ first sends $3$ to $2$, which is further moved to $1$ by $(12)$, so the composition maps $3\mapsto 1$. Finally $1\mapsto1\mapsto 2$. Altogether $(12)(23)=(123)$, an order three.permutation.

Comment: Do work with products of cycles for a while before you delve into Sylow theory.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see that now. But I thought that a general result is that I can rewrite any permutation into transpositions. That is correct, right? And two different transpositions are two disjoint cycles? I seem to have a misunderstanding here.

Comment: I think I see my mistake now. It is not necessarily the case that the permutation can be written as **disjoint** transpositions.

Comment: Transpositions $(ij)$ and $(k\ell)$ are disjoint, if $\{i,j\}\cap\{k,\ell\}=\emptyset$. That is not the case here. Correct, only relatively few permutations are products of disjoint transpositions.